# Implement IdentityServer v3 in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an application in MVC 4 using .Net Framework 4. Now i want to implement SSO (using IdentityServer v3) in application. How do I implement IdentityServer v3.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Start here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below links which has more details.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server

Comment: Is it possible to implement IdentityServer v3 using .Net Framework 4?

Comment: This is good and well for Owin based MVC apps, but what about those that dont use OWIN? The documentation makes no mention of these